# One direction UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview

I need to have my UISCrollView only accept scrolls in one direction, not only one dimension. The ScrollView contains album art for songs in a playlist on a horizontal direction. It is paged, so each cover has its own page. When the user swipes or drags the cover to the left, the next cover slides in place and the next song is played.

It should not be possible to go back to a previous song, or cover. How can i prevent this behavior?

I tried the following:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrolledView
{
    if(scrollView.contentOffset.x < (pageIndex * 320) - 320)
        [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake((pageIndex * 320) - 320, 0)];
}
```

But if i do a quick slide to the "previous" direction, the cover will slide about 150px to the "next" direction, strange.

I have also tried removing the previous covers with removeFromSuperview, but this only leaves a black space, dragging can still be done.

Lastly, i tried to move the covers:

```
-(void) reloadCoverScrollView{
    for(int i = 1; i < [scrollView.subviews count]; i++){
        [scrollView exchangeSubviewAtIndex:i withSubviewAtIndex:i - 1];
    }
    [scrollView setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

How can i accomplish what i want? The ScrollView should behave as if it was always at the first page. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. you build your own custom view
2. you change the scrollview behaviour by moving the current page at offset 0

I explain both solutions:

** CUSTOM VIEW (NO SCROLL VIEW) ***
What you need here is a scroll view where most of the useful scroll view features are removed: no continuous scrolling (but pagination), no zoom, limited content size (so you are limited to one page). 
In my opinion you should make a view controller where you instantiate two views: one is the current view, the other is the next view; the current view is visible, the next view is placed just outside the window. Then you add a single finger pan gesture and by tracking its status (it is a continuous gesture) you can slide the second view on top of the first; when you consider the swipe complete then you will finish the animation. At the end of the animation you set the new page as "first" and render the hidden second page with the next view, and so on...

** KEEP USING SCROLL VIEW **

In such case your view controller that behaves as UIScrollView delegate must behave in such way that the visible page is placed at content offset zero. So let's say you start at page 0 and you have a list of pages in the scroll view: page 1, page 2, ...
As soon as you swipe to page1 and the animation is finished, you immediately translate all view from page 1 by one page on the left (so if your page is 320px wide you will translate all subviews by 320px on the left) and you will remove the subview at page 0. Then you will reset your scroll view content offset to the origin (0,0). So at the end you will have your new page 1 set at position 0, page 2 moved to position 1 and so on. It will be impossible to scroll left but only right.
When you used "removeFromSuperview" you did the right thing but you forgot to translate the subview and reset the content offset.